# PowerShell Script to Uninstall multiple programs from a list of servers

Tags: powershell, variables, text-files

I have written a basic PS script in order to uninstall any programs defined in a text file ($appname) on all servers defined in a text file ($servers).

Running this command manually without the variables it works fine, however running the script via Jenkins or from PS command line it just hangs so I can't even debug, anyone have any ideas?

```
[array]$servers= Get-Content "D:\Jenkins\BuildUtilities\Citrix\CitrixServerList.txt"
[array]$appname= Get-Content "D:\Jenkins\BuildUtilities\Citrix\ProgramsList.txt"

ForEach($server in $servers) { 

$prod=gwmi -ComputerName $server Win32_product | ?{$_.name -eq $appname}
$prod.uninstall()

}
```

To clarify: By running manually I mean running the following:
    gwmi -ComputerName CTX-12 Win32_product | ?{_.Name -eq "Microsoft Word"}

Microsoft Word is an example.

Comment: Edit your question to clarify exactly what "works fine"--what are you running "manually without the variables"? Are you running that from your workstation? Are Jenkins and the PS command line on your workstation, or are they on a different machine?

Comment: Hi Mike, apologies please see my edit @MikeSherrill'CatRecall'

Comment: well you could start be adding lines that tell you which product you are currently uninstalling to see which server and product it is hanging on to see if there are trends there. `$appname` is an array. `-eq` is not an array operator in that fashion. You need to use something like `-contains` or `-in`. Also I do not know if you can call `.Uninstall()` on all array items at once / a good idea.  `$appname -contains $_.name` or does  `$appname` only have one line in it?

Comment: Hi @Matt I will add these lines in due course once I can get the script to work. I appreciate that it would help for debugging but I have used this method for many PS/BASH scripts and it isn't the connection to the server/s which is the problem. Appname will have approx 10 lines in it but for current testing it only has 1

Comment: I wasnt trying to suggest it was the connection that was the issue but specific software  installs on specific servers. If there were connection issues you would be getting errors which you did not mention.

Comment: @Matt I have manually logged in to the server and it does indeed have the software I wish to uninstall

Comment: Ok, let me be more specific. I had not meant that the software or server was not present but there were issues with the uninstall process of those softwares. If those were indeed hanging you would have no way of knowing.

Comment: @Matt Apologies, I didn't understand. I have tried your method though to no avail, I really have no idea!

Comment: @Matt However I now have an error message! You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\Jenkins\BuildUtilities\Citrix\UninstallPrograms.ps1:6 char:5
+     $prod.uninstall()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: This would happen if `$prod` was a null variable. You do not account for there being no software returned. What does ProgramsList.txt contain as a sample? Is it more than one line?

Comment: It contains the following: "DbLogin Admin Console"
"DbArchive Index Manager"
"DbAuthorise"
"DbCapture Admin"
"DbCapture Client"
"DbCapture Export"
"DbDeposit Client"
"DbWebAuth"
"DbWebQViewer"
"Failed Deposit Manager"
"DbArchive Export"

Answer (score 0):

It should have been easy to follow Matts hints

```
[array]$servers= Get-Content "D:\Jenkins\BuildUtilities\Citrix\CitrixServerList.txt"
[array]$appname= Get-Content "D:\Jenkins\BuildUtilities\Citrix\ProgramsList.txt"

ForEach($server in $servers) { 
    $prod=gwmi -ComputerName $server Win32_product | ?{ $appname -contains $_.name}
    $prod.uninstall()
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have followed Matts hints and it still doesn't work I'm afraid.

Comment: However I am now presented with the following error message: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\Jenkins\BuildUtilities\Citrix\UninstallPrograms.ps1:6 char:5
+     $prod.uninstall()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an comparison of two arrays, what you want to do is check for every instance of matching applications in the prod array you fetch from the server, so using the pipeline how you have it is not ideal.

```
[array]$servers= Get-Content "D:\Jenkins\BuildUtilities\Citrix\CitrixServerList.txt"
[array]$appname= Get-Content "D:\Jenkins\BuildUtilities\Citrix\ProgramsList.txt"
$DebugPreference= 'Continue'

foreach($server in $servers) 
{ 
    Write-Debug "Getting all installed applications on server $server"
    $prod= Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Scriptblock {gwmi Win32_product}
    Write-Debug "Installed applications collected, there are $($prod.Count) items in the array."

    foreach($p in $prod)
    {
        Write-Debug "Searching apps array for the name $($p.Name)."
        if($appname -contains $p.Name)
        {
            Write-Verbose -Message "$($p.Name) found on server $server, uninstalling."
            $p.uninstall()
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Verbose -Message "$($p.Name) was not found on server $server."
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Since you brought up the speed issue, using Win32_product is very slow. So the faster method would be to get a list of installed applications from the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall (details how to do that are [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/11/13/use-powershell-to-quickly-find-installed-software/)). Build a new array of applications found that need uninstalled and then call on Win32_product. Just know that this only speeds up one portion of your script, and if any application is found, the slow down will still occur. The major speed gains will come from when  you find a server that doesn't have any applications to uninstall.

EDIT2: Did some experimenting, using a simple Invoke-Command greatly speeds up the Get-WMIObject command. I did it on Services, using the command alone took 9 seconds, using the Invoke-Command took 1 second. Test:

```
$firstStart = Get-Date
$service1 = Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $ServerName  
$firstEnd = Get-Date
$firstTime = New-TimeSpan -Start $firstStart -End $firstEnd 
Write-Host "The first collection completed in $($firstTime.TotalSeconds) seconds." -ForegroundColor Green

$secondStart = Get-Date
$service2 = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -ScriptBlock {Get-WmiObject win32_service}
$secondEnd = Get-Date
$secondTime = New-TimeSpan -Start $secondStart -End $secondEnd 
Write-Host "The second collection completed in $($secondTime.TotalSeconds) seconds." -ForegroundColor Green
```

Comment: Instead of devmode you could use `write-debug` which is what that is for. Also you have a misspelling `Verbonse` => `verbose`

Comment: @Matt Thanks, that's a fantastic idea.

Comment: Hi @Paolis thanks for taking the time to answer. I am currently trying out your script in Jenkins, however it's been running for 10 minutes and still isn't  done getting all of the installed applications on the server, is there a more efficient way of doing this? Maybe just looking for the applications listed in $appname?

Comment: Yes, I would highly suggest using either Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms (if your servers have SCCM client) or just read the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall to find installed applications. I prefer the registry read myself, details about it can be found here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/11/13/use-powershell-to-quickly-find-installed-software/

Comment: @jto the slow down is just populating $prod. Not in the comparison in the arrays.

Comment: @jto see my Edit2 above in regards to your speed issue.